What does the "hits" tab indicate in the JADE 5 XRD software?
I'm doing some powder diffraction of multi-phase samples (i.e. rocks) and would love to fully understand this software (JADE 5) so that I can utilize it to best results. Using my knowledge of the system these rocks came from + some geology ± some pXRF data on the samples composition I can get the major phases pretty easily. But there are some minor phases in these hydrothermally altered rocks that could be important and I'd like to be able to narrow in on those without just visually matching peaks. That will be the final check of course but windowing down to a handful of possibilities using the software would be nice.
If someone could thoroughly explain the different tabs (FOM, Q, D, PDF-#, Hits, #d/I etc.) in the search/match window that would be incredible. FOM and Hits are really the two I've identified as most important for now however. Thanks for any help at all though!
